# Query conversion from sybase to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sybase

I have one query that is to convert from sybase to SQL server, I think we just need to change join operations.. Here is part of the query:

Can someone help me here?

```
FROM sy_trcr_divided d, fd_income_trans t 
                            WHERE d.fd_id_income is not null 
                            AND t.fd_income_transfer_id = d.fd_proc_id 
                            AND t.fd_income_est_yn = 'Y'
                            AND d.fd_id_income = a.fd_id
                            AND d.fd_dist_to_i_or_p = 'A' 
                            AND d.gl_year = :p_lYear 
                            AND d.gl_period = :p_lPeriod 
                            AND d.fd_include_stip_yn = 'Y'),0) AS ADDTO_FUND
     FROM sy_est_income_detail a,   
         fd_master  
   WHERE a.fd_id *= fd_master.fd_id and  
         a.hr_id = :p_szHRID
```

My thought: have to replace `*=` with a join.

Answer (score 0):

The `*=` should be a `left join` and the piece of the query you provided should probably be:

```
FROM sy_trcr_divided d
INNER JOIN fd_income_trans t ON t.fd_income_transfer_id = d.fd_proc_id
WHERE d.fd_id_income is not null 
  AND t.fd_income_est_yn = 'Y'
  AND d.fd_id_income = a.fd_id
  AND d.fd_dist_to_i_or_p = 'A' 
  AND d.gl_year = :p_lYear 
  AND d.gl_period = :p_lPeriod 
  AND d.fd_include_stip_yn = 'Y'),0) AS ADDTO_FUND
FROM sy_est_income_detail a
LEFT JOIN fd_master ON a.fd_id = fd_master.fd_id
WHERE a.hr_id = :p_szHRID
```

Comment: = :p_lyear is what? Its not a legal variable Sybase name or identifier?

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits I don't think they are actually; they're variables for sure but not Sybase which should use the @ syntax. Maybe from the programming language used to run the code. And thanks for the edit btw, I forgot to remove the * when I did copy-paste.